# Task<T> doesn't respond in WebApi, but returning non Task works

Tags: c#, task, asp.net-web-api

I have a method that will not return a response to the browser, I've tried using the browser itself and the chrome extension POSTMan.

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("getNotifications")]
    [AcceptVerbs("Get", "Post")]
    public Task<List<UserNotifications>> GetNotifications()
    {
        Task<List<UserNotifications>> userNotList = new Task<List<UserNotifications>>(() => new List<UserNotifications>{
            new UserNotifications()
            {
                UserId = new Guid(),
                MessageText = "Message 1",
                MessageTime = DateTime.Now,
                Status = true,
                Subject = "new message 1"
            },
            new UserNotifications()
            {
                UserId = new Guid(),
                MessageText = "Message 2",
                MessageTime = DateTime.Now,
                Status = true,
                Subject = "new message 2"
            },
            new UserNotifications()
            {
                UserId = new Guid(),
                MessageText = "Message 3",
                MessageTime = DateTime.Now,
                Status = true,
                Subject = "new message 3"
            }
        });
        return userNotList;
    }
```

However if I change the method to not return type Task...

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("getNotifications")]
[Authorize]
[AcceptVerbs("Get", "Post")]
public List<UserNotifications> GetNotifications()
{
    var newstring = "";
    List<UserNotifications> userNotList = new List<UserNotifications>{
        new UserNotifications()
        {
            UserId = new Guid(),
            MessageText = "Message 1",
            MessageTime = DateTime.Now,
            Status = true,
            Subject = "new message 1"
        },
        new UserNotifications()
        {
            UserId = new Guid(),
            MessageText = "Message 2",
            MessageTime = DateTime.Now,
            Status = true,
            Subject = "new message 2"
        },
        new UserNotifications()
        {
            UserId = new Guid(),
            MessageText = "Message 3",
            MessageTime = DateTime.Now,
            Status = true,
            Subject = "new message 3"
        }
    };

    return userNotList;
}
```

I get the following back every time

```
[
    {
        "userId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "subject": "new message 1",
        "messageText": "Message 1",
        "messageTime": "2014-05-19T11:03:32.707957-04:00",
        "status": true
    },
    {
        "userId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "subject": "new message 2",
        "messageText": "Message 2",
        "messageTime": "2014-05-19T11:03:32.707957-04:00",
        "status": true
    },
    {
        "userId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "subject": "new message 3",
        "messageText": "Message 3",
        "messageTime": "2014-05-19T11:03:32.707957-04:00",
        "status": true
    }
]
```

Why when I use task does nothing get returned to the browser on test calls directly to the webapi service?

**EDIT 1**

Changed method to this...  still sat spinning it's wheels for some reason

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("getNotifications")]
    [AcceptVerbs("Get", "Post")]
    public async Task<List<UserNotifications>> GetNotifications()
    {
        Task<List<UserNotifications>> userNotList = new Task<List<UserNotifications>>(() => new List<UserNotifications>{
            new UserNotifications()
            {
                UserId = new Guid(),
                MessageText = "Message 1",
                MessageTime = DateTime.Now,
                Status = true,
                Subject = "new message 1"
            },
            new UserNotifications()
            {
                UserId = new Guid(),
                MessageText = "Message 2",
                MessageTime = DateTime.Now,
                Status = true,
                Subject = "new message 2"
            },
            new UserNotifications()
            {
                UserId = new Guid(),
                MessageText = "Message 3",
                MessageTime = DateTime.Now,
                Status = true,
                Subject = "new message 3"
            }
        });
        return await userNotList;
    }
```

HOWEVER when I changed it to this...

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("getNotifications")]
    [AcceptVerbs("Get", "Post")]
    public Task<List<UserNotifications>> GetNotifications()
    {
        var newstring = "";
        List<UserNotifications> userNotList = new List<UserNotifications>{
            new UserNotifications()
            {
                UserId = new Guid(),
                MessageText = "Message 1",
                MessageTime = DateTime.Now,
                Status = true,
                Subject = "new message 1"
            },
            new UserNotifications()
            {
                UserId = new Guid(),
                MessageText = "Message 2",
                MessageTime = DateTime.Now,
                Status = true,
                Subject = "new message 2"
            },
            new UserNotifications()
            {
                UserId = new Guid(),
                MessageText = "Message 3",
                MessageTime = DateTime.Now,
                Status = true,
                Subject = "new message 3"
            }
        };

        return Task.FromResult(userNotList);
    }
```

It returned results fine... can anyone clarify what is the difference between these approaches.  I'm venturing into the land of Task, asnyc, and await but I still need to be able to test the calls directly to the webapi using something like POSTMan.

EDIT 2
Both of the following variations worked...

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("getNotifications")]
    [AcceptVerbs("Get", "Post")]
    public Task<List<UserNotifications>> GetNotifications()
    {
        var userNotList = Task.Run(
                () => new List<UserNotifications>{
            new UserNotifications()
            {
                UserId = new Guid(),
                MessageText = "Message 1",
                MessageTime = DateTime.Now,
                Status = true,
                Subject = "new message 1"
            },
            new UserNotifications()
            {
                UserId = new Guid(),
                MessageText = "Message 2",
                MessageTime = DateTime.Now,
                Status = true,
                Subject = "new message 2"
            },
            new UserNotifications()
            {
                UserId = new Guid(),
                MessageText = "Message 3",
                MessageTime = DateTime.Now,
                Status = true,
                Subject = "new message 3"
            }
        });

        return userNotList;
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("getNotifications")]
    [AcceptVerbs("Get", "Post")]
    public async Task<List<UserNotifications>> GetNotifications()
    {
        var userNotList = Task.Run(
                () => new List<UserNotifications>{
            new UserNotifications()
            {
                UserId = new Guid(),
                MessageText = "Message 1",
                MessageTime = DateTime.Now,
                Status = true,
                Subject = "new message 1"
            },
            new UserNotifications()
            {
                UserId = new Guid(),
                MessageText = "Message 2",
                MessageTime = DateTime.Now,
                Status = true,
                Subject = "new message 2"
            },
            new UserNotifications()
            {
                UserId = new Guid(),
                MessageText = "Message 3",
                MessageTime = DateTime.Now,
                Status = true,
                Subject = "new message 3"
            }
        });

        return await userNotList;
    }
```

Comment: try "return await userNotList;"

Comment: ... and perhaps making the method `async`. Then it should work.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? If you have (synchronous) data to return, just return it synchronously (not wrapped in a task).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've **created** the task, but **haven't actually started** it, try replacing your task constructor:

```
Task<List<UserNotifications>> userNotList = new Task<List<UserNotifications>>(...
```

with the following:

```
var userNotList = Task<List<UserNotifications>>.Run(
                    () => new List<UserNotifications>{...});
```

---

**Update**

1. Problem with edited example where you add `async/await` is the same, you create *an object that knows what to do* ~ `Task`, but you don't actually *tell to start doing that work* ~ `Run` method.
2. In the second example where you use `Task.FromResult(userNotList)`, you already have the resulting list, and simply wrap it into a *completed* `Task` and return it.

For more information on this topic, I strongly suggest you to read [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19957).

Comment: Technically correct, but `Task.Run` should not be used on ASP.NET.

Comment: Googled `task.run asp.net` and found your blog article - interesting read, thanks.